# Android ContentProvider Uri Matching

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am trying to create a content provider where the the wild card character '*' is used to match another url, for example.

```
content://com.gaurav.provider/podcast/*
```

and the * is used to match with:

```
content://com.gaurav.provider/podcast/http://www.example.com/example.mp3
```

but it isn't getting matched. Any solutions?

Comment: Use question mark ? instead of *.

Comment: there is no mention of "?" in the developer docs http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html, only wild card characters are "*" for any character and "#" for numbers

Comment: That's why I did not post it as answer, since ? is supported as wild card in case of cursors in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`content://com.gaurav.provider/podcast/http://www.example.com/example.mp3` is not a valid `Uri`. You cannot have a colon in the path.

`content://com.gaurav.provider/podcast/www.example.com/example.mp3` should work, as should `content://com.gaurav.provider/podcast/http/www.example.com/example.mp3`.